# Bootstrap4 toggle button

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 to create [a toggle button](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#toggle-states); however, on clicking the button the checkbox is not being updated, although the `active` class is being set.

Even calling `$('.btn-group-toggle').button('toggle')` sets the `active` state, but does not change the `checked` status of the checkbox.

```
<div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
    <input type="checkbox" value="0" />
  </label>
</div>
```

Is there any way to set the checked status, other than writing a click() function myself?

Comment: How did you check if the checkbox wasn't updated? Because it should work: https://jsfiddle.net/aoc3fL1o/

Comment: You're right! I was checking it with chrome dev tools, and I expected to see the `checked` value appear. I tested with a plain checkbox and the checked value did not appear. It is working, but somehow I was not adding a name, so I couldn't catch it on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan Brazier mentions, the HTML used is correct. I was missing the `name` attribute on the input, so that's why I was unable to catch it on the server. So this is the updated code:

```
<div class="btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
    <input name="my-input-value" type="checkbox" value="0" />
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code works for me - I suspect you've not got the right JS included? I second-guessed myself migrating to 4 in terms of which of the many supplied JS files I'd need to include, it's not very documented. The bootstrap.bundle.js is the catch-all one that contains everything.

Also, there are a lot of little references to dependancies or quirks in Bootstrap that aren't particularly well highlighted. So be careful to ensure you add the right aria labels etc.

Comment: Checkboxes and Radio buttons are css-only.

Comment: Vanilla checkboxes and radios themselves certainly are non-JS. But in this setting, with Bootstrap button styling wrapped around to act as a 'toggle button' JS is required.

edit: https://codepen.io/pen?template=yKLZWN - this is Bootstrap 4 current release, using @Ramses code. Try turning off JS and watch how the button no longer receives it's active state.